# Need secure site substitute for printfriendly.com

Tags: software

At the present time, the website "printfriendly.com" is not available in my work environment. I had submitted an appeal to our helpdesk to have this site reviewed. Their response: That site is a "proxy" and as such is insecure in our educational setting.

Printfriendly is a valuable tool. For example, printfriendly will remove any extraneous information from a website that one may need to display or print out. This includes all non-related links, photos, etc., making the information more organized and easier to access or read. Recreated information is then available in PDF. Very helpful, and free!

Suggestions, free or fee based are greatly appreciated.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Try Firefox "Reader Mode" or the equivalent on the browser you use. And any extension that let you remove elements (NukeAnything is one).

Comment: Chris Coyier of CSS-Tricks developed a bookmarklet called [The Printliminator](https://css-tricks.github.io/The-Printliminator/)

Answer (score 1):

Your IT department's issue with printfriendly.com isn't anything to do with that site in particular or its security. Their issue is with the concept of a website that can fetch the content of other websites and then give it to you. What they actually mean by "insecure" is "would let you circumvent our censorship". As such, they'll have the same complaint about all of the alternative sites, so there's no point in looking for one.